# how do i create the matrix from the non zero elements keeping the new matrix size same as original

Tags: matlab

I have matrices of the form

```
A=[1;2;3;4;0;0]
```

and another matrix that zeros out some elements of A for example

```
B=[0;0;3;4;0;0]
```

how can I push the non zeros elements to the first index to create a matrix like this

```
C=[3;4;0;0;0;0]
```

while keeping the length of the matrices the same.

Comment: Are the matrices always column vectors? If not, give mpre representative example with several columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is fairly self-explanatory:

```
C = [A(B ~= 0); zeros(sum(B == 0),1)]
```